# Adding columns to scrum board

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS2013 and have spent a lot of effort editing the Task WIT process to allow two new states for my tasks... "Testing" and "Blocked"... I have edited the Task.xml file on the server and successfully added the two new states and the valid transitions to and from these states.

The states do show up when editing a task and the flow to and from the new states seem to work fine.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to add these new states as swimlanes on the task board. All of the Microsoft documentation states the columns are defined by the process states.

Please not this is the "In-Sprint" task board... NOT the Kanban board (that one is easy to edit)

Here is the XMl that I have added to the Task WIT Xml :

```
    <STATE value="Testing">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
    <STATE value="Blocked">
      <FIELDS>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate">
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
        <FIELD refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy">
          <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
          <EMPTY />
        </FIELD>
      </FIELDS>
    </STATE>
```

......

```
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Testing">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Development Completed" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Testing" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Testing Passed" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Testing" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Testing failed - Fixing" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Testing" to="New">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Testing failed - Ready for fix" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Active" to="Blocked">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Impediment Encountered" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Blocked" to="Active">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Impediment Removed" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
    <TRANSITION from="Blocked" to="Closed">
      <REASONS>
        <DEFAULTREASON value="Closed due to Impediment" />
      </REASONS>
    </TRANSITION>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the new states to the process configuration?

If you use "witadmin exportprocessconfiguration" you can add your additional stated to the column mapping. You need to tell TFS wither those states should allign to "ToDo", "InProgress", or "Done" modes.

Once you have modified and uploaded this it should work.

Comment: Awesome, thanks MrHinsh... all working 100% now... for those that are interested the XML elements that I had to add my entries to were located under **ProjectProcessConfiguration->TaskBacklog->States** in the exported xml file.